# how to customize field number in jquery.formset django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

hi i built an app for a mobile store , each single IMEI has its unique IMEI , i want to entry IMEI's while i add mobiles

```
class Mobile(models.Model):
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)

class MobileStorage(models.Model):
    mobile = models.ForeignKey(Mobile,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Imei(models.Model):
    imei = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name='IMEI',unique=True)
    mobile = models.ForeignKey(MobileStorage,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

whenever i add a new `MobileStorage` for example quantity =15 , then they have 15 unique IMEIs , i need to generate 15 fields instead of increasing fields manually ?

```
class MobileStorageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    mobile = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Mobile.objects.all(),empty_label='mobiles')
    class Meta:
       model = MobileStorage
       fields = [
           'mobile','quantity'
       ]

class ImeiForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = Imei
       fields = ['imei']

MobileStorageInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    MobileStorage,Imei,form=ImeiForm,fields=('imei'),extra=1,can_delete=False
)
```

```js
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.tb1 tr:last').formset({
           prefix:'{{imei.prefix}}',
           addText:'add',
           addCssClass:'btn btn-success',
           deleteText:'delete',
           deleteCssClass:'delete-row btn btn-danger'
         })
   })
</script>
```

i know i should change `jquery.formset.js` but i dont know how todo it ?

for example `{{form.quantity | add_class:'form-control' | attr:'id:quantity'}}` in my template provide `id:quantity` then generate the number of quantities fields ?!thanks for your advice